# C言語での行列表示

Tags: c, 行列

C言語で行列を表示したいのですが, `scanf` で値を代入するのではなく, 固定値として `for` 文を利用してあらかじめ値を代入するにはどうすればよいですか.

表示結果として以下の様になってほしいです.

```
A =
  1 2 3 4
  5 6 7 8
  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: for文が必要ですか？単に２次元配列の初期値設定ではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: 今のこの発言内容では「表示」の質問なのか「代入」の質問なんだかわからないっす。どっちなのかはっきりさせてほしいです。

Answer (score 0):

１からその配列のサイズ分までループ回して、その数値を代入していけばいいですね

Answer (score 0):

3行4列をそのまま2次元配列で表現して、後は順繰り(ここでfor-loopを使用)に要素へ値を設定していけばよいかと思います。

```
    const int M = 3;
    const int N = 4;

    int A[M][N];

    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            A[m][n] = n + (N * m) + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("A = \n");
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        printf(" ");
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            printf(" %d", A[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```